# shorter way to write match

Tags: f#

I have a function that returns a tuple:

```
let rec pack l = 
            let combine = List.fold packFunction (' ',[], []) l
            match combine with 
                            | (_,b,a) -> b::a |> List.rev |> List.tail
```

is there a way to extract parts of the tuple without using a match statement?

ie, id like to get b and a out of (_,b,a) without using a match statement

Comment: Sounds like you might find this enlightening: http://fsharpnews.blogspot.com/2011/01/patterns-are-everywhere.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
let rec pack l = 
    let _,b,a = List.fold packFunction (' ',[], []) l
    b::a |> List.rev |> List.tail
```

You can always extract directly from tuples:

```
let a,b = (1,1)
```

or

```
let a,b = functionWhichReturnsTuple
```

Answer (score 2):

Pattern matching can be used in many places other than just `match`es. In this case, it doesn't appear that you need `combine` at all (nor does it appear that `pack` needs to be recursive)...

```
let pack l = 
    let _, b, a = List.fold packFunction (' ', [], []) l
    b::a |> List.rev |> List.tail
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another way to put it (patter matching via lambda argument):

```
let rec pack l =
    List.fold packFunction (' ',[], []) l
    |> fun (_,b,a) -> b::a |> List.rev |> List.tail
```